# Angular CLI production build placing duplicates of all my fonts in the root of my dist directory. Can this be avoided?

Tags: angular, fonts, command-line-interface

In my Angular project, i have custom fonts stored in src/assets/fonts/*

I reference these fonts in my styles.scss file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'museo_sans_package';
    src: url('assets/fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.eot');
...
```

When doing a production build using the Angular CLI, my fonts directory along with all the font files in it are copied to my ./dist directory correctly:

./dist/assets/fonts/*

however all of my font files are also getting duplicated into the root of my /dist directory as well resulting in 2 copies of my fonts. One in ./dist/assets/fonts/* as expected, and also in ./dist/* which i do not want.

Is there a configuration i need to set somewhere to avoid this?

UPDATE: the fonts are copied to the ./dist/assets/fonts directory because the .angular-cli.json config is set to dup assets into the dist directory.

The duplication of my fonts into the root of .dist is being caused by either the sass compiler or the angular cli build process or both in that something is modifying the paths set in the urls for my @font-face rules, changing them to point to the root rather than the relative path assets/fonts/*

my current angular install:

```
@angular/cli: 1.1.0
node: 8.0.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.1.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
@angular/language-service: 4.1.3
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding an slash at the beginning of the font url like this:

```
src: url('/assets/fonts/MuseoSans_100-webfont.eot');
```

Comment: This works but then they dont work with base-href anymore

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, after spending a lot of time on this, I ended up putting all my `@font-face` in my index.html in the `<style>` tag with paths like `src:url("assets/fonts/myFont.woff2")`. Then fonts are not duplicated anymore, they are placed in my "fonts" folder and I have no more 404 errors.

In short, my backend had a filter based on assets and I could not leave fonts in root folder. I also did not want to set up a custom webpack config. I believe some people could be in the same configuration and that's why I put it here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post, but I had been struggling with this also. I found this solution which worked perfectly for me:

[fonts of third party css in dist/root](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3143#issuecomment-411321618)

The main changes I made was changing the dot before the slash to make the URL an absolute path

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Montserrat-Light";
/*it was like this before*/
/*src: local("Montserrat-Light"), url(./assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf) format("truetype");*/
src: local("Montserrat-Light"), url(/assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Light.ttf) format("truetype");}
```

Note:

- `/` means the root of the current drive.
- `./` which means the current directory.
- `../` means the parent of the current directory.

And add my fonts file in the `angular.json` file:

```
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico",
           "src/assets",
           "src/assets/fonts"
          ],
```